# Autosave from php to mysql without page change or submit button

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, autosave

Basically I have a list of data that is shown via a foreach statement from a table in my database. I want a dropdown list next to each that has some values in them that need to be saved to a field in my table, however I want to autosave the value in the dropdown list to the field as soon as the value in it is changed. Can anyone point me to a tutorial or something that might help?

I am using php and mysql to create the system, but will happily use JavaScript if required

I have had a look at this: [dynamic Drive Autosave](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex16/autosaveform.htm)http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex16/autosaveform.htm which is similar to what i want, however i need it to actually store that data in my database not temporary storage.

Any Guidance appreciated,

Ian

---

**BIG EDIT**

So, thankyou for the replys but I have no clue about ajax call.....I found this:[How to Auto Save Selection in ComboBox into MYSQL in PHP without submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682713/how-to-auto-save-selection-in-combobox-into-mysql-in-php-without-submit-button).

can i get it to work?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').live('change',function () {
        var statusVal = $(this).val();
        alert(statusVal);
        $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "saveStatus.php",
                 data: {statusType : statusVal },
                 success: function(msg) {
                     $('#autosavenotify').text(msg);
                 }
      })
  });
});
</script>


<?php foreach ( $results['jobs'] as $job ) { ?>

          <td width="25%"><?php echo $job->job_id</td> 
          <td>
          <select name="status" id="status">
                  <option value=''>--Select--</option>
                  <option value='0'>Approve</option>
                  <option value='1'>Reject</option>
                  <option value='2'>Pending</option>
          </select>
          <div id="autosavenotify"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

and on the page saveStatus.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['statusType'])) {

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","username","mypass","rocketdb3");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("jobs", $con);

$st=$_POST['statusType'];
    $query = "UPDATE jobs SET status=$st WHERE job_id=$id";
    $resource = mysql_query($query) 
        or die (mysql_error());

}
?>
```

Comment: I use X-editable http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/

Comment: Just make an AJAX call to PHP. It is probably most frequently used technology in web

Comment: You could just use PHP's `serialize` functions to store the form element values in the DB.

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108495/on-change-of-dropdown-list-showld-call-the-php-function

Answer (score 1):

Where is the **$id** in saveStatus.php ?

You need to pass the statusType and job_id via AJAX to update correctly in the saveStatus.php.

For example:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').on('change',function () {
        var statusVal = $(this).val();
        var job_id = $(this).id;
        alert(statusVal);
        $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "saveStatus.php",
                 data: {statusType : statusVal, job_id: job_id },
                 success: function(msg) {
                     $('#autosavenotify').text(msg);
                 }
      })
  });
});
</script>


<?php foreach ( $results['jobs'] as $job ) { ?>

      <td width="25%"><?php echo $job->job_id; ?></td> 
      <td>
      <select name="status" id="<?php echo $job->job_id; ?>">
              <option value=''>--Select--</option>
              <option value='0'>Approve</option>
              <option value='1'>Reject</option>
              <option value='2'>Pending</option>
      </select>
      <div id="autosavenotify"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

*Note: `.live()` is deprecated, use `.on()` instead.

And saveStatus.php

```
$st = (int)$_POST['statusType'];
$id = (int)$_POST['job_id'];
$query = "UPDATE jobs SET status=$st WHERE job_id=$id";
```

Comment: Hi, sorry i part removed the job_id bit just to try and get something to work, the problem seems that when i change the dropdown value nothing happens as if it isn't going to the stated url, I changed it from live to on as you said but nothing.

Comment: @kaperu: Worked for me, although I was only putting the value into session for now, it still sent through perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use JavaScript (+ jQuery for easier working) to achieve this. 
Catch the 'change' of the value using JavaScript and fire an AJAX call to a PHP script that saves the value to the MySQL db.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery! On the drop-down onchange event do a ajax call and update the record in DB. Here is a link to [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method.

Comment: A bit reckless to tell someone brand new to using Ajax to just put raw user input straight into their database without properly santizing isn't it?

Comment: At first glance, I thought the point that @cerd made was moot. However, there's always the possibility, when working with HTML/JavaScript, that the user could manipulate the contents of the dropdown before submitting it and send something malicious into the database. - Something to be mindful of...

Comment: The system is only used in a small company between 3/4 people, most being the MD's so sending malicious data should not be a problem. Not having a clue about AJAX maybe :)

Comment: You can handle data as you move on. As you are on the starting point first try to integrate the ajax call and then you can change whatever way you want to save the data in database!